# Unable to generate YouTube iFrame using Dynamic Templating and Google Fusion Tables

Tags: iframe, youtube, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google fusion table that contains a youtube iframe.  When I edit the info window to something like this:

```
<div class='googft-info-window'  style='width:180px;height:100%;'>
<b>{Title}</b><br><br>
<div class='video-container'>{Youtube}<br>
<img src="{Photo}" width="180" /><br>
<a href='{Link}' target='_blank'>{Link}</a><br>
</div>
</div>
```

It displays correctly, with the youtube iframe displaying the video.

I want to use dynamic templating so that I can say something like, if the photo exists output it, if not output nothing.

I tried:

```
{template .contents}
<div class='googft-info-window'  style='width:180px;height:100%;'>
<b>{$data.value.Title}</b><br><br>
<div class='video-container'>
<br>{$data.formatted.Youtube}<br>
<img src="{$data.value.Photo}" width="180" /><br>
<a href='{$data.value.Link}' target='_blank'>{$data.value.Link}</a><br>
</div>
</div>
{/template}
```

but I can't get the iframe to generate as a youtube video, instead it comes out as plain text.  I can't find any information on how to display the video using the dynamic templating.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer.  I changed the variable from 
>{$data.formatted.Youtube}

to 

>{$data.formatted['Youtube'] |noAutoescape}

noAutoescape prevents the output from being HTML-escaped

Info from https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/functions_and_directives?hl=ru#print_directives

now the youtube iframe displays correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I had tried to do that initially but stackoverflow stated that I had to wait 8 hours since I am newer and I didn't want anyone to waste time trying to answer it since I found the solution.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I changed the variable from

```
{$data.formatted.Youtube}
```

to

```
{$data.formatted['Youtube'] |noAutoescape}
```

noAutoescape prevents the output from being HTML-escaped.  I found this information from https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/functions_and_directives?hl=ru#print_directives

The youtube iframe now displays correctly.